# match substring of a source code in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, substring

I'd like to isolate a substring of a source code in ruby, but I can't have better than this
http://rubular.com/r/ALngW9TOwy
I'd like to stop my match at the end of the first

```
<p>[...]/n</p>
```

I tried some things, but I have to admit that I suck at regex. I know there's a lot of method, like using Regexp or a simple regex, but I'm lost. If somebody can help, it would be great !
Thanks a lot !

EDIT: Thanks to Mchl, I have the solution. I put my need in the commentary, but it'll be better here:
so I use this

```
match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/m)[1].strip
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I inderstood correctly, but it seems to me, you need to 'ungreed' the `*`

`<p>(.*?)<\/p>`

Comment: Yay that's work ! But, could you explain to me ? I don't really understand why… 
It works at least on the site, irb seems to doesn't like it

Comment: I could, but I'd rather refer you to this excellent site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html - see the paragraph called 'Watch Out for The Greediness!'

Comment: interresting, didnt know that you can make .* nongreedy like that

Comment: Thank you, I will read this carefully ;)
And I make irb okay with this "match(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/m)[1].strip"

Answer (score 0):

you should try negative lookahead

```
<p>((.(?!<\/p>))*.)<\/p>
```